# Using selenium to automate process flow diagrams

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We have a web application that exposes a list of process flow control objects. These objects could be dragged from a canvas and then you can arrange them to design a process flow.  We are using Selenium C# to test the entire application. We have not yet designed tests around this though.  How would we design automated tests or is there a library we can use or package to automate the dragging and arranging of objects to create a process flow on the canvas?

Here is an example screen of what I mean by process flow diagram.  Of course we have built this into an app that uses a canvas that the user can use to create a process flow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read this https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Advanced-User-Interactions

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
    .moveToElement(otherElement)
    .release(otherElement)
    .build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: Ok. I am aware of the selenium interactions.  How do you use it to build a test that connects the components together on the canvas?  Is that possible?